# How to go inside a class in vs code by a click

Tags: laravel, vscode-extensions

I am using `VSCODE` as editor to build my `laravel` application . I saw in a video that, it is possible to  go inside a `class` just by a click on the `class name` like what the `extension` `goto-View` do . So can someone tell which extension can handle this functionality in vscode  for `classes`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download `Laravel Goto` extension. Its description and link is here:

Description: Go to various Laravel files by Alt + ;
Version: 4.2.0
Publisher: Adrian
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=absszero.vscode-laravel-goto

Answer (score 5):

For the ultimate experience on **VSCode** using **Laravel** install:

1. [Laravel Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-extension-pack)
   [image]
   [image]
2. [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)

To open the classes files **hover** over the class name then click `ctrl` + `right click`

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) You can use it. It's worked for me.